# What link do I call to Amazon s3 when I use axios

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I'm new to S3 so I didn't find anywhere in the API where it says that this is the respective URL to use for the axios URL parameter. I'm keeping on getting a 404 error saying that the

```
axios({
        url: `call/s3/backend`, 
        method: "post",
        data: {
          //images: imageArray.toByteArray(),
        },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          //imageUrlArr = res.data;
          axios({
            url: `api/petition_posts`,
            method: "post",
            data: {
              petition_post: {
                title: title,
                description: description,
                hashtags: arrayOfHashtags.join(" "),
                amount_donated: 0,
                //media: imageUrlArr,
                goal: money,
                card_type: "petition",
                org_profile_id: 1,
              },
            },
          })
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    titleError(true ? title.length === 0 : false);
    descriptionError(true ? description.length === 0 : false);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file from the browser to S3 using Axios:

1. fetch a pre-signed S3 URL from your server
2. PUT the file to the pre-signed URL using Axios

Server:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '...',
    secretAccessKey: '...'
})
const s3 = new aws.S3()
const params = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Key: 'my-file.txt',
    Expires: 300,
    ContentType: 'text/plain'
}
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params,
    (error, signedUrl) => return signedUrl /* to client */ )
```

Client:

```
const axios = require('axios')
axios.put(<signed-url-from-server>, 'abc', {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }
}).then(res => console.info(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Could you tell me where you found that?

Comment: @A.K.M.Adib [https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530](https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530).